# SQL Reporting Services - Shared Data Source in Visual Studio

Tags: database, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder, avaya

I have an web application Avaya WFO that recommends using MS Report Builder for report development.  The application has some remote data sources setup that I am able to access via a web source like http://mywebsite/ReportServer/DataSources/Source.rsds.  Outside of this application I use VS with Data Tools for SSRS development and would like to use this instead of report builder.  My trouble is I am not certain how to the remote data source for my VS project.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention what version of Visual Studio your using so the functionality may vary.  But, yes, this should be possible.  The web source you refer to is a SSRS shared data source. Per the MS documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/create-modify-and-delete-shared-data-sources-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15):

> A shared data source is a set of data source connection properties that can be referenced by multiple reports, models, and data-driven subscriptions that run on a Reporting Services report server. Shared data sources provide an easy way to manage data source properties that often change over time. If a user account or password changes, or if you move the database to a different server, you can update the connection information in one place.

So create your data project and then your report.  When prompted for the connection string simply enter your .rsds and carry on with your report writing.